# Type Hinting Eloquent Models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, type-hinting

I am trying to write good code, and part of that is type hinting to make it easier for work down the line and to force expectations.

This may seem a little contrived, but its more of a proof of concept for me.

I am writing a class to take a TSV file split on tabs and insert into my Model. In my constructor I was asking for:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
```

To which I passed:

```
new \App\Model()
```

And finally the error response of:

```
instance of App\Model given
```

Clearly I have done something wrong, but I do not want to force usage of App\Model, how can I generically ask for an eloquent model?

**Edit for more information:**

To make it more clear, I am using Laravel 5, the models are created via artisan make:model. The constructor is as follows:

```
function __construct ($resource, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model, $skip = 0)
```

And the Model I am using (for my movie table) is:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Movie extends Model {
```

Comment: I don't understand how you pass in `\App\Movie()` and it says you gave it instance of `App\Model`.  Was that a typo?

Comment: @user3158900 Yes, sorry I will update the question.

Comment: Does `App\Model` extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`? Otherwise the exception makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Bogdan It does not but it is an eloquent model. Like I said I know it is wrong, but I don't know how to actually type hint an eloquent model

Comment: Eloquent models need to extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` or another class that extends it, otherwise they're not Eloquent models. Please edit the question and post the definition of the constructor where you're type hinting the parameter.

Comment: @Bogdan Sorry it does extend Model, it has a use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; then it extends Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your type hint, preface the FQCN with a backslash:

```
function __construct ($resource, \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model, $skip = 0)
```

Either that, or add the `use` statement to your class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyClass {
    function __construct ($resource, Model $model, $skip = 0) {
        //
    }
}
```