# Type hinting for the model objects of Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, type-hinting

I haven't used laravel yet, but watching the tutorials on youtube left me with a question to type hinting, that is really important to me.

Now I have read here

[Type Hinting Eloquent Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405924/type-hinting-eloquent-models)

and here

[Eloquent ORM Code Hinting in PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439753/eloquent-orm-code-hinting-in-phpstorm)

but neither addresses the following problem:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Movie extends Model {
}
```

now lets say movie has a name, id, length, author

all those fields are not defined in the class movie, but somehow come automagically from the active record ORM eloquent model [if I understood correctly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3PsPHqYRfQ)

But let's be honest, I wont remember if it was called `author`, `Author` or `AuthorName`. Or `MovieLength`, `Length` or `TotalTime`

how should i remember all of that for ALL models? is there a way to type hint this in php storm?

i mean the fields from all tables in all models.

**EDIT**

to make it more clear

i want to type:

```
$m = App\Movie::find(1);
$m->|
```

where `|` is my caret. Now what fields do I have on the class Movie?

Comment: I find that your question is unclear. What and where are you trying type hint? Or are you referring to your IDE on hinting to attributes/methods of a particular class when you are typing a statement. I find that using dd(); helper function can be a life saver if you don't mind using the CLI or browser.

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: `/* @var $varName Type_Name */` works for type-hinting Eloquent in Netbeans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1798793/470749

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to install the laravel-ide-helper ServiceProvider package in your application

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Seems to have a lot of helpful features for type hinting to the IDE.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Weird. Try this link to the github repo https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: I don't actually use PHP Storm (I use Sublime). I just know of the package and its capabilities being close to what you're looking for

Comment: this is _exactly_ what I was looking for. Just remove your broken link and add that link instead. Actually just did that

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper which is free there is

https://laravel-idea.com/
which is a lot better but has monthly subscription

There is as well a package I'm a back fan of which is:
https://github.com/reliese/laravel

which auto generates the models for you and includes phpdoc as well. Thus improving autocomplete as well. E.g. instead of doing the work twice of 1) writing migrations then 2) writing models you just write the migrations (properly with foreign keys etc) and then reliease will generate the models automagically for you with right naming etc and throw phpdoc on top so you can see the fields